# Get Joining two VertexPartitions with different indexes is slow in Spark and GraphX by unpersist graph

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Sorry about the inaccurate and long title, if you can understand what I'm saying, please help me edit it, thanks.

The code is as follows. If you execute it, you will get

```
14/06/12 14:33:24 WARN ShippableVertexPartitionOps: Joining two VertexPartitions with different indexes is slow.
```

But if you comment `graph.unpersistVertices(blocking = false)`, then there will be no such warning.
So I'm curious about why this will change the index of `Graph` object?

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
      .setMaster("local[4]")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val v: RDD[(VertexId, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Seq((0L,0),(1L,1),(2L,2)))
    val e: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(Seq(Edge(0, 1, 0), Edge(0, 2, 0), Edge(1, 0, 0), Edge(2, 1, 0)))


    val g = Graph(v, e)

    def test(graph: Graph[Int, Int]) = {
      graph.cache()
      val ng = graph.outerJoinVertices(graph.outDegrees){
        (vid, vd, out) => (vd, out.getOrElse(vid, 0))
      }

      val f = ng.subgraph(epred = _.srcId != 0, vpred = (vid, vd) => vid != 0L)
      f.cache()
      graph.unpersistVertices(blocking = false)
      f
    }

    val f1 = test(g)

    println(f1.numVertices)

  }
}
```

According to my knowledge, when you do a manipulation, like `mapValue`, on a GraphX's Graph, the index of `RDD`(`VertexRDD`) will be reused to avoid re-computation. When you do something like subgraph, you will still some sort of reuse those indexes by applying bit mask on it. Does `outerJoinVertices` some kind of manipulation since it only modify the value of a RDD?

Moreover, I `cache()` the new graph before `unpersist` the older one, so I think the `unpersist` will not affect the cached graph since we already cached it, but I'm wrong.

How does the cache and unpersist work? Why they will affect the indexes since I'm not actually joining partitions?

Update: I look into the code and `numVertices` is actually a map and reduce method 
`partitionsRDD.map(_.size).reduce(_ + _)`. So the joining happens at this line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to materialize the new graph before unpersisting the old graph. This is because RDD *transformation*s are lazy operations, i.e., spark dose not actually compute them until it sees an *action*. For more information, refer to "RDD Operations" in the spark programming guide: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

So in your test function, simply add one line of code after f.cache() solves the issue:
f.vertices.count //this *action* will force spark to compute f and cache it