# Spark's GraphX: Why am I getting "Joining / Diffing two VertexPartitions with different indexes is slow" even after having persisted involved RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, join, spark-graphx

I am running the following snippet using GraphX:

```scala
val g = Graph(
      v.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER),
      e.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER),
      1,
      StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER,
      StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

val pageRankResult = g.pageRank(0.0001)
```

I am warned at runtime with:

- `[WARN - org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.ShippableVertexPartitionOps]  - Diffing two VertexPartitions with different indexes is slow.`

and

- `[WARN - org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.ShippableVertexPartitionOps]  - Joining two VertexPartitions with different indexes is slow.`

I read the answer of the topic [Get Joining two VertexPartitions with different indexes is slow in Spark and GraphX by unpersist graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191823/get-joining-two-vertexpartitions-with-different-indexes-is-slow-in-spark-and-gra), but in my case everything is persisted.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use a `_SER` suffixed storage level in order to leverage the fast zip join of `VertexPartitions`.

Switching from `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` levels to `MEMORY_AND_DISK` might make you gain in computation time (and you will not see warnings anymore) but the cached data will take more space.